# Discreteness of eigenvalues for certain operators - can this approach be made rigorous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, intuition

I was idly thinking about why one might naïvely expect a discrete spectrum of eigenvalues for a linear operator $L$ when I dreamt up the following argument (which I expect isn't new instead - references?). **Can it be made rigorous**, with any necessary added restrictions, or does it at least offer some genuine informal insight? (Or did I just mess something up?)

---

Suppose $L$ is a linear, self-adjoint operator acting on (sufficiently) continuously differentiable functions  $\phi:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with boundary conditions $\phi(0)=\phi(1)=0$. An eigenfunction $\phi_\lambda(x)$ is a non-zero such function such that

$$\left[L \phi_\lambda\right](x) = \lambda \phi_\lambda(x)$$

We expect that such functions occur only for 'discrete' $\lambda$, in particular not for an interval $(a,b)$ of eigenvalues. *Clarification*: I'm thinking of $L$ being a 'nice' integral/differential operator in my head. What I'm interested in is what further restrictions are necessary to make the spectrum simple.

---

Here's a reason to suspect this is the case: suppose $\phi\equiv \phi(x;\lambda)$ is a (sufficiently) continuously differentiable function $[0,1]\times(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $L \phi = \lambda\phi$. Suppose further that $L,\phi$ is sufficiently nicely behaved that $L (\partial_\lambda \phi) \equiv \partial_\lambda(L\phi)$. Note that we expect $\partial_\lambda \phi|_{x=0,1}=0$ since all $\phi$ obey the boundary conditions, so $L$ should be self-adjoint on this function too.

Then, with a simple $L^2$ inner product $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>$ say,

$$\boxed{\lambda \left<\phi,\partial_\lambda \phi\right> = \left<L\phi,\partial_\lambda \phi\right> = \left<\phi,L\partial_\lambda \phi\right> = \left<\phi,\partial_\lambda L\phi\right> = \left<\phi,\partial_\lambda (\lambda\phi)\right> = \left<\phi,\phi\right> + \lambda \left<\phi,\partial_\lambda \phi\right>}$$

and hence
$$\left<\phi,\phi\right> = 0$$

Hence there is no *continuously differentiable* family of solutions which vary the eigenvalue throughout some interval.

**Example** By contrast, if we dropped our boundary conditions and worked on the fully infinite domain $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$ the operator $Lf=f''(x)$ acquires all real eigenvalues on the smooth families $\cos kx,\exp kx$. But for s finite interval with homogeneous BCs, we only get e.g. $0,\pi,2\pi,\ldots$

---

Any interesting thoughts are welcome! I haven't thought about this in great detail, so it may be that this just leads to a standard spectral theory argument when one tries to make it rigorous, but I'm curious as to whether it has an interesting interpretation, and whether you think it would be a good, informal justification to teach someone first coming to Sturm-Liouville theory.

Mainly, I am interested in whether this can be tweaked to a proof without losing all the simple spirit of the boxed equation above.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is very interesting. I'm not sure how to best adapt it yet.

The standard arguments would say that eigenfunctions in $L^{2}$ with different eigenvalues are orthogonal. Because $L^{2}[0,1]$ is separable (has a countable orthonormal basis), then there can be at, most, a countably-infinite number of eigenvalues.

For non-singular Sturm-Liouville equations on a finite interval, the classical eigenfunctions are in $L^{2}[0,1]$, but do not always satisfy the correct boundary conditions. However, one can find classical eigenfunctions $\phi_{\lambda}$ which satisfy one of the two endpoint conditions $C(\phi_{\lambda})=0$. By proper normalization, $\phi_{\lambda}$ will be analytic in $\lambda$ and not the trivial zero solution; then the true eigenvalues occur when the second condition $d(\lambda)=D(\phi_{\lambda})=0$ is satisfied. You end up with the eigenfunctions being the zeros of an analytic function $d(\lambda)$. So the eigenvalues are isolated for non-singular problems on finite intervals.

The situation changes for singular Sturm-Liouville problems, where the spectrum may be continuous, and there are no actual eigenvalues because the classical eigenfunctions are not in $L^{2}$, even though "wave packets" of them (resembling expressions such as $\int_{\lambda-\epsilon}^{\lambda+\epsilon}\phi_{\alpha}d\alpha$) are "approximate eigenfunctions" in $L^{2}$. So simple arguments break down (as they must) because the classical $\phi_{\lambda}$ for real $\lambda$ are not necessarily in $L^{2}$, and cannot be used as vectors in an inner-product, except as wave packets.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! I'm aware this is a bit of a queer question, so it's well appreciated. I'm just curious to see any relation with actual analysis. (Someone pointed out the separability argument to me recently, and indeed this gives a much better one-line argument to my mind.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm puzzled by the fact that you are taking derivatives with respect to $\lambda$: is that a typo?

Regarding the "discrete eigenvalues" thing: let $V$ be any infinite-dimensional inner-product space. Let $\{e_n\}$ be a countable orthonormal set, and let $\{q_n\}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$. Define an operator $L$ by 
$$
Le_n=q_ne_n,\ \ \ L=0\ \mbox{on the orthogonal complement of }\{e_n\}.
$$
Then the set of eigenvalues of $L$ is $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$.

Comment: It's not a typo! I'm not doing general linear operators, but pleasant differential/integral ones, e.g. Sturm-Liouville. I want $L$ to be a nice expression acting on a function $\phi$. I'm taking derivatives wrt \lambda$ is to show there's no *smooth* family for which the eigenvalue *smoothly* varies. The thing I feel I'm missing is the possibility of an interval of eigenvalues with $\phi$ not varying differentiably with $\lambda$, and I would like a condition excluding this possibility. Also, a simple condition on $L$ excluding sets of eigenvalues like yours would be nice. Will clarify.